# Renumbering a column based on occurrence of a string

Tags: awk, sed, seq

Fairly new to linux, I apologize.

I have a file as such:

```
1   C   foo   C     bar
2   C   foo   C     bar
3   C   foo   C     bar
4   H   foo   H     bar
5   H   foo   H     bar
6   O   foo   O     bar
```

And I need to get it to be:

```
1   C01 foo   C     bar
2   C02 foo   C     bar
3   C03 foo   C     bar
4   H01 foo   H     bar
5   H02 foo   H     bar
6   O01 foo   O     bar
```

**Unfortunately the spacing between foo and C as well as the spacing between C and bar must be maintained.

I have tried it in a piecewise manner, where I pull out lines containing the different identifiers, C, H, and O, placing them in a temp file. Then I attempt to order them by occurance, and then splice the original file back together.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    sed -i -e "/ C /w temp1.txt" -e "//d" File.txt
    sed -i -e "/ H /w temp2.txt" -e "//d" File.txt
    sed -i -e "/ O /w temp3.txt" -e "//d" File.txt


    `awk -i '{print NR $2}' temp1.txt
    awk -i '{print NR $2}' temp2.txt
    awk -i '{print NR $2}' temp3.txt

    cat temp1.txt >> File.txt
    cat temp2.txt >> File.txt
    cat temp3.txt >> File.txt
```

However I am pretty sure my syntax is awful, as I am really only familiar with sed rather than awk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same solution while preserving the initial field positions

```
$ awk '{r=sprintf("%02d",++a[$2]); sub($2"  ",$2r)}1' file

1   C01 foo   C     bar
2   C02 foo   C     bar
3   C03 foo   C     bar
4   H01 foo   H     bar
5   H02 foo   H     bar
6   O01 foo   O     bar
```

Note that this assumes first field values don't overlap with the second field values as shown, otherwise you need to guard to keep changes only to the second field.  For second field it can be easily done by prefixing match and replacement values with single space.

Comment: Thank you so much! This saves me a ton of time.

Comment: @WagnerAG hopefully you'll do something useful with the saved time :)

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Here is a solution with GNU `awk` which preserves actual spaces. If your `split` supports 4 arguments. After reading man page I got it, even I am happy that I found it, it will be helpful.

```
awk '
{
  n=split($0,array," ",b)
  array[2]=sprintf("%s%02d",array[2],++a[array[2]])
  line=b[0]
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    line=(line array[i] b[i])
  }
  print line
}'  Input_file
1   C01   foo   C     bar
2   C02   foo   C     bar
3   C03   foo   C     bar
4   H01   foo   H     bar
5   H02   foo   H     bar
6   O01   foo   O     bar
```

About `split` in GNU `awk` man page for 4 arguments:

> ```
>    split(s, a [, r [, seps] ])
>                            Split the string s into the array a and the separators array seps on the regular expression r, and return the
> ```
>
> number of fields.   If
>                                  r  is  omitted,  FS  is used instead.  The arrays a and seps are cleared first.  seps[i] is the field
>   separator matched by r between
>                                  a[i] and a[i+1].  If r is a single space, then leading whitespace in s goes into the extra array element
>   seps[0] and trailing white-
>                                  space goes into the extra array element seps[n], where n is the return value of split(s, a, r, seps). 
>   Splitting behaves identically
>                                  to field splitting, described above.

---

---

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following,

```
awk '{$2=sprintf("%s%02d",$2,++a[$2])} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 C01 bar C
2 C02 bar C
3 C03 bar C
4 H01 bar H
5 H02 bar H
6 O01 bar O
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to have values in $2 and $4 both places then do following.

```
awk '{$2=$4=sprintf("%s%02d",$2,++a[$2])} 1'  Input_file
1 C01 bar C01
2 C02 bar C02
3 C03 bar C03
4 H01 bar H01
5 H02 bar H02
6 O01 bar O01
```

***3rd solution:*** In case you want to add/insert a new column at last of line then do following.

```
awk '{$(NF+1)=sprintf("%s%02d",$2,++a[$2])} 1'  Input_file
1 C bar C C01
2 C bar C C02
3 C bar C C03
4 H bar H H01
5 H bar H H02
6 O bar O O01
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you! Now if I needed to change the column to column 4, I would simply replace the occurances of $2 with $4?

Comment: @WagnerAG, you mean 2 and 4 should have same values?

Comment: @WagnerAG, please check my EDIT solutions and let me know if those helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your help @RavinderSingh13 I have edited my post above to reflect what I mean

Comment: @WagnerAG, please check my EDIT solution now and let me know?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\S/\s` shorthand for `[^[:space]:]]/[[:space:]]`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(\S+\s+)(\S+)(.*)/,a){ printf "%s%s%02d%s\n", a[1], a[2], ++cnt[a[2]], a[3] }' file
1   C01   foo   C     bar
2   C02   foo   C     bar
3   C03   foo   C     bar
4   H01   foo   H     bar
5   H02   foo   H     bar
6   O01   foo   O     bar
```

The above will work on **ALL** input, even if a preceding field has the same values as the target field or if the target field contains RE metachars or anything else.

The above is to modify the 2nd field. in general to modify the n-th field for n=4, say, hard-coded would be:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/((\S+\s+){3})(\S+)(.*)/,a){ printf "%s%s%02d%s\n", a[1], a[3], ++cnt[a[3]], a[4]}' file
1   C   foo   C01     bar
2   C   foo   C02     bar
3   C   foo   C03     bar
4   H   foo   H01     bar
5   H   foo   H02     bar
6   O   foo   O01     bar
```

and if it's passed as an argument rather than hard-coded:

```
$ awk -v n=4 'match($0,"((\\S+\\s+){"n-1"})(\\S+)(.*)",a){ printf "%s%s%02d%s\n", a[1], a[3], ++cnt[a[3]], a[4]}' file
1   C   foo   C01     bar
2   C   foo   C02     bar
3   C   foo   C03     bar
4   H   foo   H01     bar
5   H   foo   H02     bar
6   O   foo   O01     bar
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple awk script:

```
$ awk '{$2=sprintf("%s%02d",$2,++a[$2]);}1' file
1 C01 foo C
2 C02 foo C
3 C03 foo C
4 H01 foo H
5 H02 foo H
6 O01 foo O
```

Comment: This is the one! Thank you! I have one issue however; In the actual file I am using there are columns with different spacings, and after use of this, the formatting falls apart. So if the above file also had the word bar 5 spaces away, it now becomes single spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Though Perl is not tagged, it seems to be good fit for these cases. Check out this, if you are considering Perl.

```
> cat wagner.txt
1   C   foo   C     bar
2   C   foo   C     bar
3   C   foo   C     bar
4   H   foo   H     bar
5   H   foo   H     bar
6   O   foo   O     bar
> perl -pe 's/(\s+)(\S+)(\s+)/sprintf("%s%s%02d%s",$1,$2,++$kv{$2},$3)/e ' wagner.txt
1   C01   foo   C     bar
2   C02   foo   C     bar
3   C03   foo   C     bar
4   H01   foo   H     bar
5   H02   foo   H     bar
6   O01   foo   O     bar
>
```

Thanks to Karakfa, the answer can be further shortened by removing $3

```
>  perl -pe 's/(\s+)(\S+)/sprintf("%s%s%02d",$1,$2,++$kv{$2})/e ' wagner.txt
1   C01   foo   C     bar
2   C02   foo   C     bar
3   C03   foo   C     bar
4   H01   foo   H     bar
5   H02   foo   H     bar
6   O01   foo   O     bar
>
```

One more way by further removing one more group

```
> perl -pe 's/([^^]\S+)/sprintf("%s%02d",$1,++$kv{$1})/e ' wagner.txt
1   C01   foo   C     bar
2   C02   foo   C     bar
3   C03   foo   C     bar
4   H01   foo   H     bar
5   H02   foo   H     bar
6   O01   foo   O     bar
>
```

or using look-arounds

```
perl -pe 's/([^?!]\S+)/sprintf("%s%02d",$1,++$kv{$1})/e ' wagner.txt
```

Comment: @karakfa if I do that, then the %02d formatting would result in ````C  01```` there will be a space between C and 01

Comment: OK, you have to replace two spaces with the digits.  `sprintf` needs to change accordingly.

Comment: yes.. I think $3 is not needed here.. let me check and update

Comment: just found one more way ````[^^]\S+````

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{$6="";$7=((b=++a[$5])>9?"":0) b}1' file file file file
1   C01 foo   C     bar
2   C02 foo   C     bar
3   C03 foo   C     bar
4   H01 foo   H     bar
...
6   O03 foo   O     bar
1   C10 foo   C     bar
2   C11 foo   C     bar
```

Explained:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=""                 # empty field separators
}
{
    $6=""                     # null $6
    $7=((b=++a[$5])>9?"":0) b # $7 carries the count, with leading 0 if below 10
}1' file
```

Comment: or `$6=int(++a[$5]/10); $7=a[$5]%10`